# UIView Subclass initWithFrame not being called?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a custom UIView subclass.  In IB, I have specified a "placeholder" UIView and set the class to my class name.  My override of drawRect method is working, and the background is coloring properly, but the initWithFrame is not firing.  Why?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSLog(@"initWithFrame");
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        noteTextFont = [[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] retain];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [backgroundColor set];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIColor *labelColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [labelColor set];
    [notificationLabel drawInRect:CGRectMake(44, 18, rect.size.width-20, rect.size.height) withFont:noteTextFont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];

    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Comment: can you show the code where you create the custom view?  Are you calling: 
 UIView *fred = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];

Answer (score 52):

Things loaded from a nib are inited with `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder`

Answer (score -2):

because you are initializing this view from a nib it looks like, so it is using the default (UIView's) initWithNibName: instead of initializing using initWithFrame:

Comment: So is it then impossible to override the initialization in the subclass?  Another question.  In IB, the view is set to be 50pt tall, but it's being initialized with a frame that is 42pt tall.

Comment: i would try overriding init: as well and see if it gets called. I forgot that UIView does not actually have initWithNibName. that is a method in UIViewController