# On iPad, the initWithFrame of a new class based on UIView is not called?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

For a single view app, a DrawView class is added, which is a subclass of the UIView class.

It is used as the main view for the app, so the `drawRect` method of this class works well, can draw things, for example, but the code generated by Xcode has a line "// Initialization code" to indicate putting init code right there, inside of `initWithFrame`, but I put some code in there and it is not called, and a break point is set there but it never stops there?  I then added an `init` using the usual method and it is not called either?

Comment: Is the view being loaded from a nib?

Comment: it is set as the view to use for the default ViewController.xib... is that the same as loaded from a nib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try overriding -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder. I believe when a view is loaded from a nib it uses this init method. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425598/uiview-subclass-initwithframe-not-being-called) question.

Comment: if `initWithCoder` is added with no initialization code, then the `initWithFrame` breakpoint will get triggered (and any initialization code will run there)... and also the background color set on the Interface Builder won't be used.  It is all black.  Is it possible to use the color set in Interface Builder?

Comment: Are you sure that you need to override the init, or can you use awakeFromNib? (Allows you to do custom initialization after the nib has been loaded.)

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you'll potentially use the class both from NIB and instantiating from code, just create some sort of -commonConfiguration method (or similar name) and call it from both places. Then your init code is in one spot.

Answer (score 1):

- initWithCoder: -**It is recommended that you Implement this method if you load your view from an Interface Builder nib file** and your view requires custom initialization.The nib-loading code does not use the initWithFrame: method to instantiate new view objects. Instead, it uses the initWithCoder: method that is part of the NSCoding protocol.***The nib-loading code does not use the initWithFrame: method to instantiate new view objects. Instead, it uses the initWithCoder: method that is part of the NSCoding protocol.***[apple's doc](http://UIView%20reference%20page%3a)
- initWithFrame: - The default initialization method for views,The new view object must be inserted into the view hierarchy of a window before it can be used. If you create a view object programmatically, this method is the designated initializer for the UIView class.

some more information here for :[overriding methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW23)

happy to help:)